# How do I fix '... is not a registered namespace' Django 2.1 error

Tags: python, django

so Im building and simple mooc plataform using Django 2.1 and Im having a problem.

[Here](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc) you can find my entire project but ill describe all situation above, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJtv8.jpg) u can find a entire printscreen of django error.

So i have this project called TamerMooc, this project has 2 apps. A core app and a courses app.

This is the /courses/views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Course

def index(request):
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    template_name = 'courses/index.html'
    context = {
        'courses':courses
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def details(request, slug):

    course = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'courses/details.html'
    context = {
        'course': course
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

And this is the /courses/urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index ,name='index'),
    path('<slug:slug>', views.details , name='details'),
]
```

And at least the /core/templates/base.html file quoted in the error file.

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Simple MOOC - Uma simples plataforma de ensino a distância" />
    <title>Tâmer MOOC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-fixed pure-menu-horizontal">
            <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="{% url 'home' %}">TÂMER MOOC</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="pure-menu-selected"><a href="{% url 'home' %}">Início</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Cursos</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}"}>Contato</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}

        <div class="footer">
            Tâmer MOOC - Uma simples plataforma de ensino a distância
        </div>

    </div>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.12.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I really read a lot of questions here on stackoverflow about similar errors but cant find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is [here](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/blob/df41cc8f7e7c7d699d98a272d5ff35e9cfac6009/courses/templates/courses/index.html#L14).

```
 <a href=" {{ course.get_absolute_url }}  "> <!--- {% url 'courses:details' course.slug %}--->
                                             ^^^^^                                        ^^^^
```

In django template, comments does not work in this way. If you want to comment out something do it like this:

```
{% comment %}
    {% url 'courses:details' course.slug %}
{% endcomment %}
```

Or

```
{# url 'courses:details' course.slug #}
```

Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#comments).

Comment: Ok that works but, after this I remove the coments of the function `get_absolute_url ` (I was thinking that the problem was here so I comment just for test) that u find [here](https://github.com/tamercuba/tamermooc/blob/master/courses/models.py) and the problem returns, U can see the error [here](https://imgur.com/a/V6XKyCq).
So, in resume, I just remove the comment that u apoint, and "add" the function ` get_absolute_url`.
Thank you for the answer, Im learning a lot!

Comment: In that case, you need to add `namespace` in your urls.py. Example can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#namespacing-url-names . But if you do that, then update urls in template like`{% url 'index' %} --> {% url 'courses:index' %}`